# Undefined index in array element

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

seem to be experiencing something strange.  I am loading an Excel file's data into an array.  I am handling things like so

```
foreach ($data->toArray() as $value) {
    dd($value);
    if(!empty($value)){
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            dd($v['id']);
            $insert[] = [
                'id' => $v['id'],
                'name' => $v['name']
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the first `dd()` (laravel output) produces something like so

```
array:809 [▼
  0 => array:20 [▼
    "id" => "123"
    "name" => "something"
  ]
  ...
```

So I can see there is an array element called id.  The second dd, which calls this array element, produces the output `123`

The problem comes where I am filling the array with this data.  Although I am still using `$v['id']` which works for the output, within the array I get the error

> Undefined index: id

Why would this be the case when the index is there?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the error refers to another index and not the first one. Are you sure that all arrays have id and name property?

Comment: instead of `dd()` use `dump()` and check when it fails..

Comment: it's probably because the next indexes ,  `1,2, .. etc => array:20 [▼
    "somevar" => "something"` don't contains such `"id"=>..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an if to check if the keys really exist in your array. This will avoid situations when the key does not exist and the `Undefined index: id` error appear.

```
foreach ($data->toArray() as $value) {
    if(!empty($value)){
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            if (array_key_exists("id",$v) &&
                array_key_exists("name",$v)) {
                $insert[] = [
                    'id' => $v['id'],
                    'name' => $v['name']
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```